# How to add two spacecharacters while uncommenting a line in .yml file from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, yaml

I have a shell script in which using sed command i am uncommenting one line in a `config.yml` file which is as below:

```
#  FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "1766687946907911"
```

But after uncommenting using a sed command, space characters are getting removed as below :

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "1766687946907911".
```

How do i retain the space characters

My script code is as below :

```
line='#  FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "980888827611"'
sed -i "/${line}/ s/# *//" config.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sed command `s/# *//` removes first `#` followed by zero or more spaces (`*`).

Try this :

```
sed -i "/${line}/ s/^#//" config.yml
```

It removes `#` at start of the line.

Comment: Thank you . It really helped me. Thanks so much